# Receiving data via LAN on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've writtem simple program on Python in Windows which send something to Raspberry Pi via LAN. But when I type for example 1 RPi receives 49. It's because I've used UTF-8 encoding? Yesterday I tried to replace this line of code with s.send(text), but it didn't work for me. Program on Raspberry Pi runs in Python3. When I run it on Python2, everything works fine even with UTF-8 encoding. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: this could be better asked in [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please read [How to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question according to it. (provide example of what you tried, format your question to make it easier to read etc ..)

Comment: I've sent image what I've tried

Comment: Do not post code within an image. How do you expect others to test it? We're to take the time to re-type it all back out? Please, read through the entirety of the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are displaying the ASCII codes of the characters you are sending.

To test this, in a python shell try:

```
ord('1')
ord('2')
```